# How to random color half of the words within h2 tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I would like to know how to color almost half of the words within `<h2>...</h2>` tag with a random color.
The color should be randomly selected from a list of specified ones.

Example

**Markup**:`<h2>This is sample text</h2>`

**Result**: *This is* sample text (The italics region i.e almost first half should be colored with a random color)

Comment: Please show us your code so far.

Comment: You haven't posted any code, i don't think you have tried to attempt to create this yourself. If you want the simplest solution via CSS use the `nth` child element. Or alter the code i have posted below to fit your spec.

Comment: I don't know javascript and that's why I seek your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the clean html code that generated by slideshow

```
<div class="slides-container">

    <h2>
        <span>he secret of getting ahead is</span>
        getting started.
        <span>-Mark Twain  </span>
    </h2>

    <h2>
        <span>You are never too old</span>
        to set another goal or to dream a new dream.
        <span>-C.S.Lewis</span>
    </h2>

    <h2>
       <span>
       If you can dream it</span>, you can do it.
       <span>-Walt Disney</span>
    </h2>

</div>
```

this array defined colors

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];
```

Change the first `Span` color in each `H2` Tags :

```
$('.slides-container h2 span:first-child').each(function(){
    $(this).css(
       'color',
        colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE V2](http://jsfiddle.net/8ocwjdwn/1/)

Comment: this just colours different h2s, not words within a single h2

Comment: That's what I need to achieve but is there any way to avoid use of two h2s. Also can i avoid wrapping it in different divs.

Comment: Is there a away to random color the first half of the h1 and generate the html code for it.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example of doing it to each character, might help you. You can change the modular to take more characters or even word.

**HTML:**

```
<h2 class="styles">This is a sample post</h2>
```

**CSS:**

```
.color_red{
    color:red;
}
.color_green{
    color:green;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.styles').each(function(){
    var letters = $(this).text().split(' ');
    $(this).text(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            $(this).append('<span class="color_red">' + letters[i] + ' ' + '</span>');
        }
        else{
            $(this).append('<span class="color_green">' + letters[i] + ' ' + '</span>');
        }
    }
});
```

All im doing is assigning a different class to the letters in an alternative method.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/v9xjn9c2/1/

**Jsfiddle v2 - Words only:** http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/v9xjn9c2/2/